# SQL Query for list within select where field = value and otherfield = othervalue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to fudge an existing SQL Server procedure rather quickly. It's a bit of a hack job but needs must.

I need for the following to return a list of voucher codes and invoice numbers rather than just one row of data where the comment is (in the WHERE clause):

```
SELECT TOP 10         
    IH.INH_Voucher AS [ID], IH.COY_ID AS COY_ID, 
    IH.INH_DateSupInv AS ORD_UpdatedOn, 
    V.VES_ID, V.VES_IMOnumber, IH.INH_Order,
    IH.INH_ID AS ORD_ID, IH.INH_INDID                    
FROM          
    InvoiceHDR IH (NOLOCK)     
INNER JOIN 
    VESSACCOMP VA ON IH.COY_ID = VA.COY_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    Vessel V ON VA.VES_ID =  V.VES_ID                   
WHERE 
    v.VSS_ID IN ('01') AND 
    (IH.INH_Status >= 20  AND IH.INH_Status <= 40) AND
    --IH.INH_Voucher = '170CH' AND IH.INH_SupInv = '1532' NEED LIST
    IH.INH_INDID IS NOT NULL
```

So I would need

```
Voucher = '1700CH' AND SupInv = '1235' AND
Voucher = '180CH' AND SupInv = '1111' AND
```

And so on for many matching `VoucherCodes` and `InvoiceCodes`.

I hope this is clear?

Thanks.

Comment: Do You have a list of that matchng voucher + Codes? Or Do You have them stored in table?

Comment: Hi, no they are all coming from values in an Excel sheet

Comment: so stored procedure should take pair of numbers from excel file in certain location, use them and at the end select what You current query selects but for all the pairs?

Comment: Yes, it has to select for all of the pairs.

Comment: Sounds like you need `(Voucher = '1700CH' AND SupInv = '1235') or (Voucher = '180CH' AND SupInv = '1111') or etc.`

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the following WHERE clause to your query:::

```
WHERE
    v.VSS_ID IN ('01') AND 
    (IH.INH_Status BETWEEN 20 AND 40) AND
    ((IH.INH_Voucher = '170CH' AND IH.INH_SupInv = '1532') 
    OR (IH.INH_Voucher = '180CH' AND IH.INH_SupInv = '1111'))         
    AND IH.INH_INDID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried that but it doesn't work. I suppose I'm needing something like: SELECT * FROM INVOICEHDR WHERE (INH_Voucher, INH_SupInv) IN (('1706CH','I8725'),('1700CH','CAT-20174'))

Comment: @Martin, in the question you said you wanted a List. maybe if you remove the "TOP 10" from your query and then try, you may get a list (of more than 10 records)